# base64 decoded image does not download

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following scripts to convert html canvas to png and let the client download it without saving the image to server. These scripts worked in xampp and also in the server cuccfree.cc. But the same scripts doesn't work in the server that i need it to be hosted.

**Javascript**

```
         fname = fname || 'picture';

        var data = cnvs.toDataURL("image/png");
        data = data.substr(data.indexOf(',') + 1).toString();

        var dataInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        dataInput.setAttribute("name", 'imgdata') ;
        dataInput.setAttribute("value", data);
        dataInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

        var nameInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        nameInput.setAttribute("name", 'name') ;
        nameInput.setAttribute("value", fname + '.png');

        var myForm = document.createElement("form");
        myForm.method = 'post';
        myForm.action = url;
        myForm.appendChild(dataInput);
        myForm.appendChild(nameInput);

        document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
        myForm.submit() ;
        document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
```

**PHP scipt**

```
<?php
    # we are a PNG image
    header('Content-type: image/png');

    # we are an attachment (eg download), and we have a name
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $_POST['name'] .'"');

    #capture, replace any spaces w/ plusses, and decode
    $encoded = $_POST['imgdata'];
    $encoded = str_replace(' ', '+', $encoded);
    $decoded = base64_decode($encoded);

    #write decoded data
    echo $decoded;
?>
```

but this is the output i get when i clicked on the button which is assigned to the javascript function.
http://oi57.tinypic.com/2je1cva.jpg

How can i correct this error??? please help me....

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the php extensions in php.ini in the different servers you are working with. May be an extension is missing in your production server.